# Buck converter design using MCP1630V

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, current-sensing

I have already designed a buck converter with the following specifications using an MCP19035:

Vin=14V, 
Vout=1.8V, 
Fc=63kHz(Crossover frequency), 
Vref=0.6V, 
Iout=10A
step load High IOH=7.5A
step load low IOL=2.5A
Fsw=600kHz

My design is working perfectly and I got the expected outputs

Now, I want to design the same converter with the same specifications, using MCP1630V. I have used the circuit given bellow, with the same calculated components for the voltage divider network, the compensation network, and power stage network. Unfortunately my design does not work as expected and I could not figure out the problem

The only thing that I think could be the source of the problem is the ramp generator circuit used in CS pin of this component

please, try to figure out what is the problem in my design

[image: My buck converter circuit]

Comment: Can you explain a little clearer about how the design is not working? Do you have any oscilloscope outputs or data we can see?

Comment: The output of MCP19035 is more stable and clean (in terms of chattering) than the output of MCP1630V, and I think the problem is in the ramp generator circuit, please try to focus on the ramp generator circuit